# Ruby on Rails 3 actionmailer subject line issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, subject

I really need some help and I've spent the last few days how to figured out what went wrong on this little thing.

My spec:
Rails 3.2.8
Ruby 1.9.3
Actionmailer 3.2.8

I can send email without problem but the subject line is not working. No matter what value I put under :subject and the email subject always is the method name which is "commentadded" in this case.

For example:

```
class Notification < ActionMailer::Base 
default from: "xxx@xxxx.com"


def commentadded (users,ccusers, project) 
    @msgsub = "Comment of #{project.title} has been created"           
    @users = users.collect(&:email).join(",")          
    @ccusers = ccusers.collect(&:email).join(",") 
    @project= project
    mail(:to => @users, :cc => @ccusers, :subject => @msgsub )  
    mail.deliver

end

end
```

I have tried hardcode the subject line :subject => "testing subject" but the subject still is "commentadded"

And when I set the default subject line on the top of the file (default subject: "XXXXX"), then it works but that's not the way i wanted since I have different kind of email templates.

I appreciate any helps.

Thanks,

Wing

Comment: Could you post the entirety of the Mailer file in question?

Comment: Can you update your code now that you've renamed the @subject variable?

Comment: Any solution? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the name `@subject`. Change the variable name and things should work...

See [here](http://www.threetwelvecreative.com/blog/posts/using-body-and-subject-in-rails-3-1-actionmailer-mailer)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I just tried rename @subject to other name, still using the method name as subject line. Even I hardcoded the subject line as :subject => "testing subject" and it is still showing the wrong one.

Comment: I addition to changing the call to the mail method, did you eliminate the use of @subject in your code?